# About the origin of the quote 所爱隔山海，山海亦可平

Tags: classical-chinese, culture, history, literature, saying

A 网友 drew my attention to a quote which I find recorded in different variations online, e.g. on [Baike Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%89%80%E7%88%B1%E9%9A%94%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%EF%BC%8C%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%E4%BA%A6%E5%8F%AF%E5%B9%B3/24380284) as 所爱隔山海，山海亦可平. It's attributed there to a collection of works called 山木诗词全集.

My question is: What is the correct quote, where in Chinese literature does it appear originally and who has said it first?

If this can't be answered, as the quote is some sort of folklore saying, I'm happy with an answer with some literary works who cite this saying as a reference.

I am also very much interested in the work 山木诗词全集. I basically find no information about it online. Who is the author and when did it appear?

PS. The Bing-AI gives me nonsense answers here...

Comment: Google tells me at least three different versions. (1) [山海不可平](https://www.getit01.com/p20171224664949668/) (2) [山海皆可平](https://www.ximalaya.com/ask/q1181986?source=m_jump) (3) [山海亦可平](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E6%89%80%E6%84%9B%E9%9A%94%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%EF%BC%8C%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%E4%BA%A6%E5%8F%AF%E5%B9%B3/24380284). I knew none of them until I read this question.

Comment: These are the three versions I found as well. @Nobody

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://www.zhihu.com/question/27487905). I have no idea if what they said are true.

Comment: I found this as well. But I thought the author from the poem from 2005 took the line from somewhere else, some ancient source. At least this line, not the whole creation. I don't fully understand the zhihu post, as I'm not Chinese. Does this also answer where the name collection of mountain and tree poems comes from? @Nobody

Comment: Can you extract from this zhihu post the name of the potential author? @Nobody

Comment: Probably totally unrelated, but that's not classic Chinese.

Comment: Maybe I mistagged - sorry @fatpenguin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出处 -《山木诗词全集》：

- “所爱隔山海，山海不可平，海有舟可渡，山有路可行。此爱翻山海，山海俱可平。- 李思圆著．这一世的美好，皆因一个你：文汇出版社，2017.07：第105页

https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%89%80%E7%88%B1%E9%9A%94%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%EF%BC%8C%E5%B1%B1%E6%B5%B7%E4%BA%A6%E5%8F%AF%E5%B9%B3/24380284

Comment: 我知道这个网页，但是不给我答案是谁的作家写的。我还没有知道什么版本是对的：不可平，还是其他 @Nobody 提到了

Comment: Is Li Si Yuan the author?

Comment: [This one](https://ppfocus.com/0/cu103e21c.html) mentions :  「所愛隔山海，山海不可平」出自《木蘭詩詞全集》 But, I cannot find it in 木蘭詩詞全集 . It's my bed time now, would you please help us to verify it ?

Comment: The author is 李思圆. I can't find 《木蘭詩詞全集.

Comment: Internet in Mainland is amazing. [Someone says](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/500014235857946804?bd_page_type=0&pu=&init=middle) : 所爱隔山海，山海亦可平这句话延伸出自唐朝著名诗人李白的《山木诗全集》但是其实是网友自己模仿的. Do you believe it ?

Comment: The AI attributed it to 文康, probably because my previous question was about him

Comment: I suggest getting the book titled "这一世的美好，皆因一个你", by 李思圆 (the author). It might contain more information on this poem.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been discussed on Chinese forums:
https://www.zhihu.com/question/27487905

It's a modern composition made in 2005, by an Internet user called littlesen.

According to the linked page, littlesen is also known as 小森 (literally: little forest), which would explain the name 山木诗词 (literally: Mountain and Wood Poems), presumably a collection of his works made by another Internet user. However there is no evidence that these works are formally published, nor can I find any still accessible page of his works.

I don't think this sentence comes from any ancient source, given that most classical works are now digitally searchable. If you were to ask me the inspiration behind this sentence then I would likely point to:

所爱隔山海: Possibly mutated from 所思在远道 (My beloved one is far away from me) of 《涉江采芙蓉》. Note the very similar grammatic structure. The latter poem is very famous but we do not know its author. It was collected in a 6th century book 《文选》.

山海不可平: Possibly a reference to two mythologies 精卫填海 and 愚公移山. In both stories the protagonist is obstructed by seas and mountains, and they try to remove the obstacle (by filling the sea with stones, by breaking down the mountain).

Comment: From the three variants discussed, which one is the correct? What is the real name of 小森? I noticed that your answer contradicts the previous...

Comment: We don't know the real name. Most Internet users won't expose them. The linked page says the original version is 山海不可平.

Answer (score 0):

The mountains and oceans are figurative barriers between the author and the one the author loves. One of them must be the son or daughter of someone very important, the other just an ordinary person.

In Baidu I found this:

所爱隔山海 山海皆可平的意思是什么？

意思是爱的人与我相隔高山大海，
The meaning is, the person I love is separated from me by high mountains and great oceans,

是我总不能越过的山海，
these mountains and oceans are impossible to cross,

但为了这份爱，
but, for this love,
我也可以乘船横渡；
I will cross the ocean in a ship,

山道再险，我也可以寻路穿行。
mountain paths are dangerous, (but) I will find a way over.

这句话最早是littlesen当年发表在北大未名bbs诗词歌赋版，
This phrase was first published by Littlesen on the Beijing University Unnamed BBS Poetry and Songs Edition,

意思是爱的人与我相隔高山大海，
the meaning is the person I love is separated from me by high mountains and great oceans,
是我总不能越过的山海，
it is impossible for me to cross these mountains and oceans,
但为了这份爱，我也可以乘船横渡；山道再险，我也可以寻路穿行。
but, for this love, I will travel the ocean by boat; mountain paths are dangerous, (but) I will find a way over.
这句话最早是littlesen当年发表在北大未名bbs诗词歌赋版，
This phrase was first published by Littlesen on the Beijing University Unnamed BBS Poetry and Songs Edition,

原作发表日期是2005年5月30日，
originally published on the 30th May 2005,
原句是所爱隔山海，山海不可平。
the original phrase was 所爱隔山海，山海不可平。

意思是说我和我的爱人远隔天涯海角，
the meaning is, I and the person I love are worlds apart,

这山山海海不可填平。
these mountains and seas (barriers) cannot be flattened.

“所爱隔山海”是指：
“所爱隔山海”refers to：
彼此之间相隔比较遥远，
the distance between us is comparatively great,
会较为困难艰苦。
(it) will be relatively arduous and difficult (to cross).
为此受到的阻碍会大，
Because of this the obstacles will be great,
需要克服的困难也多。
many difficulties need be overcome.
两个人间的爱却是如同隔了山海。
The love between the two is like being separated by mountains and seas.
“山海不可平”是指：山海横亘在我们之间，
“山海不可平”refers to: between us is all mountains and seas,
仅凭一己之力无法穿过这高山大海。
(if we) only rely on our own strength there is no way we can cross these high mountains and vast oceans.

扩展资料：
Extended information

喜欢就去大胆去追，趁年轻，
(If) you like someone pursue that person boldly, avail yourself of your youth,

别畏惧别羞涩别顾虑太多，做自己想做的，爱自己喜欢的。
forget fear, forget shyness, forget misgivings, do what you want to do, love the one you want.

不管结果如。
regardless of the outcome.

Obviously, the author has never heard of jet planes, which cross mountains and oceans without any trouble!

Baby I love you, baby I love you, baby I love only you! Yeah!